# UWP app .cs file inheritance static variable from xaml.cs

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have created a PlayPage.xaml, PlayPage.xaml.cs and Game.cs file.
The PlayPage.xaml.cs has two variable, windowWidth and windowHeight.

I would like access two public static variable from Game.cs.

**Game.cs:**

```
namespace UwpApp
{
    class Game
    {
        static Rectangle rectangle;
        PlayPage pg = new PlayPage();

        //Create a rectangle
        public Rectangle draw()
        {
            rectangle = new Rectangle();
            rectangle.Width = 70;
            rectangle.Height = 70;
            rectangle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            Canvas.SetLeft(rectangle, randPos());
            Canvas.SetTop(rectangle, randPos());
            return rectangle;
        }

        //Create a random X and Y position
        private Int32 randPos()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            Debug.WriteLine(pg.windowWidth);
            return rnd.Next(0 , (int)pg.windowWidth);
        }
    }
}
```

**PlayPage.xaml.cs:**

```
namespace UwpApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class PlayPage : Page
    {
        DispatcherTimer timer;
        Rectangle rect;
        bool isTapped;
        public static double windowWidth, windowHeight;

        Game game = new Game();

        public PlayPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            startCounter.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            isTapped = false;
        }

        private void Load_Variable(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            windowWidth = canvas.ActualWidth;
            windowHeight = canvas.ActualHeight;
        }

        //Counter animation. (Number opacity, fall)
        private void counterAnimation()
        {
                startCounter.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

                //Set Counter Horizontal Align
                double left = (canvas.ActualWidth - startCounter.ActualWidth) / 2;
                Canvas.SetLeft(startCounter, left);

                Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();

                DoubleAnimation opacityAnim = new DoubleAnimation();
                DoubleAnimation fallAnim = new DoubleAnimation();

                opacityAnim.From = 1;
                opacityAnim.To = 0;
                opacityAnim.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                opacityAnim.AutoReverse = false;
                opacityAnim.RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(3);

                Storyboard.SetTarget(opacityAnim, this.startCounter);
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(opacityAnim, "(UIElement.Opacity)");

                fallAnim.From = -115;
                fallAnim.To = canvas.ActualHeight / 2;
                fallAnim.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                fallAnim.AutoReverse = false;
                fallAnim.RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(3);

                Storyboard.SetTarget(fallAnim, this.startCounter);
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fallAnim, "(Canvas.Top)");

                storyboard.Children.Add(opacityAnim);
                storyboard.Children.Add(fallAnim);

                storyboard.Begin();
        }

        //Countdown Timer
        private void countDown()
        {
            timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Tick += startCounter_CountDown;
            timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            timer.Start();
        }

        //Change Countdown value
        private void startCounter_CountDown(object sender, object e)
        {
            int counterNum = int.Parse(startCounter.Text);
            counterNum -= 1;
            startCounter.Text = counterNum.ToString();

            if (counterNum == 1)
            {
                timer.Stop();
                StartedGame();
            }
        }

        //Tap or Click to start the game
        private void TapToStart(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(!isTapped)
            {
                isTapped = true;
                counterAnimation();
                countDown();
                this.TapToStartText.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }

        //Create rectangles
        private void StartedGame()
        {
            rect = game.draw();
            canvas.Children.Add(game.draw());
            Debug.WriteLine(windowWidth.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

One more thing: I get an error this line: PlayPage pg = new PlayPage();
[Error (pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqaDy.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error in your picture is due to infinite recursion, as it says.  The constructor for Game instantiates a new PlayPage.  The constructor for PlayPage instantiates a new Game.  Which instantiates a new PlayPage.  Which instantiates a new Game.  and on and on.

Static members are accessed by class name, not by instance.  Like so:

```
PlayPage.windowWidth
```

Comment: Also, `static` data is best avoided in UWP.